# Resetting scale in Phaser

Tags: javascript, game-engine, phaser-framework

I have a game made in phaser and we're trying to add fullscreen functionality to it. When I call just

```
this.game.scale.startFullScreen(false);
```

it keeps the games maxHeight and maxWidth, since they're set in the preload, so it shows a black full screen with the game centered, so I created a wrapper for it, which works, but not when a user hits escape as opposed to the "Exit fullscreen button". The start wrapper sets the maxWidth and maxHeight to null, which then allows total full screen, and the stop wrapper sets them back to their default values, and when you press the "exit fullscreen" button it works fine, but when I hit escape it calls my function, but doesn't reset the screen, so it exits browser full screen mode, but is still taller than the browser window.

Here's my full code:

```
var startFullscreen = function() {
    // remove maxwith and maxheight
    game.scale.maxWidth = null;
    game.scale.maxHeight = null;

    // set to fullscreen
    game.scale.startFullScreen(false);
}

var stopFullscreen = function() {
    // reset maxWidth and maxHeight
    game.scale.maxWidth = 1000;
    game.scale.maxHeight = 600;

    // turn off fullscreen
    if (game.scale.isFullScreen) { // if the user hit escape, fullscreen is already exited and we only need to reset the scale
        game.scale.stopFullScreen();
    } else {
        // what goes here?
    }
}

$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) { // escape key maps to keycode `27`
        stopFullscreen();
    }
});
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried this: http://phaser.io/docs/2.4.4/Phaser.ScaleManager.html#refresh ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved the resetting to after we go to full screen, that way they're already set when exit full screen gets called, so it renders correct, but I'm still open to better solutions.

```
var startFullscreen = function() {
    // remove maxwith and maxheight
    game.scale.maxWidth = null;
    game.scale.maxHeight = null;

    // set to fullscreen
    game.scale.startFullScreen(false);

    setTimeout(function () {
        // resets height and width so the game will render correctly when fullscreen exits
        game.scale.maxWidth = 1000;
        game.scale.maxHeight = 600;
    }, 500);
}
```